# Is it possible to add multiple projects at once in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I know that I can add more than one project to a solution, but I have a load of pre-developed projects that I want to add and rather than going

> Add > Existing Project > Navigate to folder > click on project file

I wondered if there was an easier way to add lots of projects at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from editing the Solution file directly, I can't see another way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Is possible programmatically through [EnvDTE COM interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e105c68.aspx) (the code is in python 2.7):

```py
dte = win32com.client.Dispatch("VisualStudio.DTE.9.0")
sol = dte.Solution
for file in files: sol.AddFromFile(file, False)
```

If there are many projects, at some point it can fail with `0x80010001` (Call Was Rejected by Callee) 'cuz VS is busy. Then just retry from that point on.